# How do I copy DVDs

Tags: dvd

Preamble:

We are down to the final stages for creating a school-play dvd. Editing is almost done, discs are printed and ready. Just need to burn the dvd's now. However, doing our pencil calculations, if we burned every disc with our production computer (  Apple G5 , taking a estimated 10-20 minutes ) we don't really have enough time to finish all the DVD's ( 100 or so )  before deadline. ( 11 hours away ).

The solution to this problem is to include my linux laptop into the burning process to reduce the workload.

So my question is:

If I had one DVD ( no security encryptions or licencing issues ) and I wanted to make 20 perfect copies really fast. What tools would I need and and what how would I use them?
Would prefer command line here.

Bonus question:

Any tips on speeding up the Apple's Burn Proccess? Using Pro Studio 4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not very difficult.

```
dd if=/dev/dvd of=saved.iso

for i in {1..20}; do
    eject /dev/dvd
    read -p 'Insert disc and press RETURN: '
    eject -t /dev/dvd
    growisofs -Z /dev/dvd=saved.iso
done
eject /dev/dvd
```

Comment: Adding `bs=10M` (±1 order of magnitude) to the `dd` command line is likely to make it observably faster.

Comment: Oops, forgot: some DVD players won't be happy unless you use `growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/dvd=saved.iso`.  If you've already burned some disks without `-dvd-compat`, you can fix them with `growisofs -dvd-compat -M /dev/dvd=/dev/zero`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go through the command line, [`k3b`](http://k3b.plainblack.com/) is the KDE burning software. I'm not sure what gnome would use.

Comment: KDE or CLI? there is not comparison...

Comment: Well it all depends if you run Kubuntu (like I do) or not.